# How to make Postgres (Docker) accessible for any IP remotely?

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, dockerfile

I'm creating a PostgreSQL container using the following command:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456789 -d postgres:9.3.6
```

which will download the required base image, and create a container.

When I check the service connectivity using telnet I get:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 5432

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

It works properly using `127.0.0.1` as the IP address, but if I use my computer's IP address, the console gets stuck and after a long while it gives me a timeout error.

```
$ telnet 191.115.52.110 5432

Trying 191.115.52.110...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

What should I do in order to have my PostgreSQL container accessible from any IP?

I have tried passing a config attribute like this. However when I do, the container exits immediately (perhaps it crashes).

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456789 -d postgres:9.3.6 -c "listen_addresses = '*'"
```

When I execute `show listen_addresses` to get the listen_addresses runtime attribute, I get `*` which means the parameter was set to `*` correctly, but still it doesn't work.

```
postgres=# show listen_addresses;
 listen_addresses 
------------------
 *
(1 row)
```

Comment: If you ran that same command without `-d` you would be able to at least see the error message so you could troubleshoot (the answers below are almost certainly the actual problem, just thought this would be helpful)

Comment: "listen_addresses='*'" CANNOT contain space characters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to create *postgresql.conf* whith parameters, and set **listen_addresses = '*'**

attach when starting your container.

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456789 \
 -d postgres:9.3.6 \
 -c config_file=/path/to/postgresql.conf
```

next solution. 
Create Dockerfile and add follows:

```
FROM ubuntu

# Add the PostgreSQL PGP key to verify their Debian packages.
# It should be the same key as https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8

# Add PostgreSQL's repository. It contains the most recent stable release
#     of PostgreSQL, ``9.3``.
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

# Install ``python-software-properties``, ``software-properties-common`` and PostgreSQL 9.3
#  There are some warnings (in red) that show up during the build. You can hide
#  them by prefixing each apt-get statement with DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-software-properties software-properties-common postgresql-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3 postgresql-contrib-9.3

# Note: The official Debian and Ubuntu images automatically ``apt-get clean``
# after each ``apt-get``

# Run the rest of the commands as the ``postgres`` user created by the ``postgres-9.3`` package when it was ``apt-get installed``
USER postgres

# Create a PostgreSQL role named ``docker`` with ``docker`` as the password and
# then create a database `docker` owned by the ``docker`` role.
# Note: here we use ``&&\`` to run commands one after the other - the ``\``
#       allows the RUN command to span multiple lines.
RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
    psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker';" &&\
    createdb -O docker docker

# Adjust PostgreSQL configuration so that remote connections to the
# database are possible.
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf

# And add ``listen_addresses`` to ``/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf``
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >> /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432

# Add VOLUMEs to allow backup of config, logs and databases
VOLUME  ["/etc/postgresql", "/var/log/postgresql", "/var/lib/postgresql"]

# Set the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

Build an image from the Dockerfile assign it a name.

```
$ docker build -t my_postgresql .
```

Run the PostgreSQL server container (in the foreground):

```
$ docker run --rm -P --name pg_test my_postgresql
```

Connecting from your host system
$ docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
5e24362f27f6        my_postgresql:latest   /usr/lib/postgresql/   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:49153->5432/tcp                    pg_test

$ psql -h localhost -p 49153 -d docker -U docker --password
```

Comment: This simply throws the error (when executing without `-d`): `/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 73: exec: config_file=postgresql.conf: not found`

Comment: because of you have to create this file and determinate the properties

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Can you please confirm in the below command "U" is user name? psql -h localhost -p 49153 -d docker -U docker --password

Comment: @SukanyaPai `-U`  means `username`, or you can write full parameter 
`--username=username`

Comment: make sure your `-c config_file=...` goes at the end of the invocation, after specifying the image `postgres` otherwise you'll get `invalid argument "./postgresql.conf" for "-c, --cpu-shares" flag: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "./postgresql.conf": invalid syntax`

Answer (score 5):

As I remember, the basic official postgresql docker image only allow to connect locally, that means the config `listen_addresses='127.0.0.1'`.

To fix it, please go inside your container, update file `postgresql.conf` the configuration `listen_addresses='*'`, and then restart your container.

Comment: mine was preset to `'*'`

Answer (score 3):

I made it, I had to open the port in my router. Dumb mistake, considering I have done this before, but somehow I forgot today. All the other answers are correct in that `listen_addresses` needs to be `*` though.

In order to check whether it is or not, you can execute `show listen_addresses;` in the `postgres=#` console.

Comment: Thanks for the command to show the listen addresses!